# Jquery autocomplete custom data error no such method 'instance' for autocomplete widget instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am adding the autocomplete functionality to text box.
Referring [this](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) jQuery autocomplete custom data plugin.

Without custom data code it is working fine. I have added following custom data code

```
 .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                        return $( "<li>" )
                          .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
                          .appendTo( ul );
                      };
```

it throws error as

> no such method 'instance' for autocomplete widget instance

is there anything that I am missing.

I am using jQuery v1.11.2 and jQuery UI - v1.10.3

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Updated the syntax for the new version: I think they are not using instance now.

```
       $("#Id").autocomplete().data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem =  function( ul, item ) 
       {
         return $( "<li>" )
         .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
         .appendTo( ul );
       };
```

Comment: it was `.data("ui-autocomplete")` for me

Comment: It was catcomplete for me. To see what it might be for you, `console.log($("#Id").autocomplete().data())`

Comment: Why are items not selectable? I've implemented your solution and works fine for subitems. Problem is, I can not select those items.

Comment: @FrenkyB check console for possible JS errors. I had to recreate whole <li> (with proper css classes) to get it to work.